# Perform CRUD operation on json using angular.?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json

Generated a `.json` file using php from my SQL database.
I am using angular in frontend and php as backend.
`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$rows = array();
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $rows[] = $r;
}

print json_encode($rows);
$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($rows));
fclose($fp);
```

I need to perform CRUD.How should i do that so my `.json` file automatically updates.?

Comment: Why are you generating a .json file from database? can you not simply pass the json from php to angular and do the operations and then update the database accordingly?

Comment: I am showing the contents of my json file using angular. Dont want to show content directly via php

Comment: alright.. Can you not grab whole of the json from your .json file and do the operations and overwrite the whole file again?

Comment: Don't u think then everytime database changes it will reload the whole json file.

Comment: Am saying that can you take the whole of your .json file content into angularjs variable and then do your operations on it. And after you are done with all the CRUD operations, overwrite the .json file with your updated Angularjs Json variable.

Comment: Why this approach? Why can't you go for the PHP makes json for you and your angular uses it?

Comment: I am using the same approach. I am asking that after crud operations on json generated from php how will my database update

Comment: You mean to say you have question regarding passing the changes from angular to php ?

Comment: I actually wanted to know if i can update my json file according as my db or vice versa

Comment: Thing is your json file you can request after some operation, and your php code can create new one for you. Also to pass changes from angular to php you can go through $http.get and .post methods in angular. Also always remember that scope variables should get updated when you make the changes, for that just request the json file from php again and load it in your scope variables. Makes sense?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `change.php` or `update.php` file which will simply overwrite your `.json` file on the server side when executed.

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
file_put_contents('file.json', $data);
?>
```

Now, you can fetch the `file.json` from server by `$http.get()` and store it into your $scope or any other variable in angularjs.

Then you may do your CRUD operations on that variable.

All you need to do now is to call the `$http.post('URL/chage.php',YOUR_VARIABLE)`

This will simply overwrite your .json file with new content.
So whenever you request to get json from `.json` file, you will always get the updated content.

Comment: Is there any other process i can use instead of generating json file

Comment: Yes there is. Its not a good practice to generate .json file for such operations. @RinkuMalik

Comment: Let me know if you want an explanation about it @RinkuMalik